# Show exactly full content in WordPress without escape tags

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I want to show limit latest post of WordPress in main page. I'm using WordPress APIs and functions to show that, but after that `get_the_content()` remove and escape all of seved tags and my posts don't show correctly such as editor tags.

This function escape HTML tags:

```
        <ul style="list-style: none;margin:5px" class="latest-posts">
            <!-- LOOP START -->
            <?php $the_query = new WP_Query( 'showposts=3' ); ?>
            <?php while ($the_query -> have_posts()) : $the_query -> the_post(); ?>
                <!-- THIS DISPLAYS THE POST THUMBNAIL, The array allows the image to has a custom size but is always kept proportional -->
                <li> <?php the_post_thumbnail( array(100,100) );?></li>
                <!-- THIS DISPLAYS THE POST TITLE AS A LINK TO THE MAIN POST -->
                <li>
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
                        <?php the_title(); ?>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <!-- THIS DISPLAYS THE EXCERPT OF THE POST -->
                <li>
                    <?php echo mb_substr(get_the_content(), 0, 1200).'&nbsp;...'; ?>
                </li>
                <!-- READ MORE LINK -->
                <li><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">more ...</a></li>
            <?php endwhile;?>
            <!-- LOOP FINNISH -->
        </ul>
```

Comment: if that `get_the_content()` contains html, then your substr operation is almost certainly going to slice tags in half, leaving you with a pile of broken html.

Comment: scape? seved? That doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: @MightyPork this function remove all html tags for me. how to resolve that?

Comment: `mb_substr` is just `substr` that understands multi-byte characters, hence the `mb` prefix. Either way, this is not a good approach, as explained by @MarcB. It's just not gonna work, if the `get_the_content()` function returns html.

Comment: @MightyPork , with `mb_substr` i want to get 1200 chars of full content. can i set this function setting to have this feature? i'm using `sahifa` theme and this theme have own summary content settings

Comment: To have what? Auto-close html tags you slice off, and remove those you cut in half? No Idea how you'd do that. Maybe try to parse the result of what you get, and complete the tags... but seriously, you seem to have no idea what you're doing in PHP. "ima hack this bit I copied from somewhere into my wordpress, it's sure gonna work"-kind of thing. My impression, anyway.

Comment: @MightyPork this line `<?php echo get_the_content(); ?>` don't show exactly my posts. after clicking on link i can see correctly formatted post. but that function remove formatted post :(

Answer (score 0):

There are basically three possibilities how to output the excerpt of the post content.

- with [`the excerpt()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_excerpt) function, to output the content of the excerpt field in post editor, if it's not filled it will display the first 55 words of the post content ( use [`excerpt_length`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_excerpt#Control_Excerpt_Length_using_Filters) filter to control the length of the excerpt ).
- to use the `<!--more-->` quicktag, [`the_content()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/the_content) tag will only show the excerpt up to the `<!--more-->` quicktag. That quicktag will not work in single pages templates.
- to manually strip HTML from post content and to show custom excerpt. One way to do that is to use [`wp_filter_nohtml_kses()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_filter_nohtml_kses) function:

  ```
  echo mb_substr( wp_filter_nohtml_kses( get_the_content() ), 0, 1200 );
  ```

All methods above will strip the HTML from post content. To include HTML in excerpts use excerpt field in post editor, WordPress will preserve HTML you included in post editor. There are also some plugins like [Advanced Excerpt](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-excerpt/) that will create excerpt from content and preserve html, but I don't believe that there is a bullet proof way of doing that.